# Windows Pin Keyboard does not work on particular user profile

Tags: windows, keyboard, windows-11, login

My daughter's pin on Windows is not working to log in. When she tries to log in she can only enter numbers - that is to say the number keys on the keyboard work but none of the letter keys work.

When she has tried to log in too many times it stops working and puts up the message that she should enter in a particular key sequence to allow her to try again. When this screen is active she can enter in letter keys.

As soon as it goes back to password field it is again only allowing her to enter numbers.

If we switch to my account on the computer I can enter both numbers and keys and log in on my account. So it seems to be limited to her account.

The num lock is not on.

We have tried restarting, putting usb for keyboard on multiple keyboard ports.

So I need to know what could be causing this and since she cannot log in to her account because her password has more than numbers in it, either I can change her password from my account which has admin rights to only use numbers or I can change whatever setting is only allowing her user to use numbers when attempting to log in.

On Edit - further information.
If I turn on the On Screen keyboard with my Daughter's account it doesn't work with letters either - only numbers.

If I type more than 3 numbers the 4th number functions as though I pressed the enter key, causing the pin to be submitted, which of course fails.

Also, just for my personal interest, anyone have any description of what clever functionality this is supposed to enable? It seems one of the stupider things I've ever encountered with Windows.

Comment: got out of the problem by starting the forgot pin process which allowed us to get in somewhere along the line, but I sure would like to know what combination of features made windows only allow 3 numeric characters for a login - and not allow the user to enter any non-numeric characters.

Comment: PIN (as in Personal Identification Number) is, by definition, numeric. Passwords acan and often are alphanumeric. PIN and password are two different user authentication methods alongside with biometrics, if available.

Comment: That's nice but the text on my Windows login on her machine says PIN not password and it is alphanumeric (phrased this way because haven't looked at any other windows version and machine in a while so hard to know if differences)